# How to retrieve the data source of the active layer?

Tags: pyqgis-3

I am trying to get the data source of the layer in the Python action within the layer property. My code in the Python action is:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
QMessageBox.information(None, "parDir: ", layer.source())
```

When I run the action, the script returned the following error:

```
An error occurred during execution of following code:
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
QMessageBox.information(None, "parDir: ", layer.source())
```

If I run the same script in the Python console, it has no problem returning the name of the data source.

Does anybody know why the script failed if I run it as Python action?

Comment: I've found the problem with the script. I need to add the following for the script to work: 
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox